# How to retrieve the value of a label in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, label

I have a situation where i was asked to change text fields into labels.  My lead wants to make sure the user does not confuse the text field for a field that the user can enter data and wants a label instead.  I made the changes necessary. But when i try to retrieve the value of the label from the form, the httpservletRequest request method returns a null value for that field.  I got a workaround by using a hidden text field with the same variable that is used in the label and that works.

I would like to know: is there a way to pass label data to the request.getparameter, and if not, why not? I suspect that since it is a label it does not pass anything, but would like to know exactly why not.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the jsp/html code associated with these labels.

Comment: I don't believe you can.  Only form variables get submitted to the server.  The question I might ask is if it's being displayed on the screen, the information was already available on the back-end, so could you put the data in the session instead?

Comment: HTML `<label>` has no `name` attribute. Therefore, it is not rendered as a request parameter to server and you can't use `request.getParameter('paramName');` to retrieve its value on the server side. You may want to use an HTML hidden field against each label for this purpose -`<input type='hidden' id='someId' name='someName' value='someValue'/>`.

Comment: @Lion Can you explain how to do it with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the label values in the `HttpServletRequest` as only form variables are sent by the browser.

Browser can send the values for text fields, hidden fields, etc., but I don't think it going to send the label values(text) with the request.

But I don't understand why would you want to retrieve the label's value in the servlet?

One thing you can do is to have a hidden field for each label and keep a value in it.

But I don't think that's going to be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  That's what i started to use: hidden text field with the variable.  The reason was because my boss and my lead wanted to use labels instead of textboxes so that the users would not get confused.

Comment: but why would you want the label values at server side

Comment: i am not sure i understand your question.  This is an application that i am supporting that has been written in 2001.  The JSP had textboxes whose values were retrieved from the request.  The leads do not want that - textboxes - they thought that instead of using textboxes, even when i made them readonly, that users would get confused and thought that labels were more appropriate.  The problem was that the variables for the textboxes which are also being used to fill the label aparently returned a null value whenever i made a request to the page. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Could you make the text boxes read only and change the font via CSS to remove the box around them?  I bet that would accomplish your goal.

Comment: That's what i had done originally but bosses did not like that. I really could not understand why but the label seemed to have worked, except that it did not.  And using the hidden field i am basically duplicating the previous work, but your idea of using the CSS to remove the box around is a good idea, that might actually work well.  Thank you so much for all the precious info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<label>` you could use `<input type="text" readonly="true" value="foo"/>`  Then you could create a CSS style for read only inputs.

```
.input[readonly] {
  /* styles remove text boxes and format as a label */
}
```

Comment: It would take me some research to get the right styles in there.  If anyone has something already and can improve the answer, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: But it is quite easy for someone to remove this CSS using some tools like firebug.

Comment: Lion, are you saying that as a warning? Because maybe i do not want to use CSS, however this is an internal app and if they use firebug to mess with the app, it's on them.

Comment: @ofilha Chrome or FireBug (in Firefox) can be used as a development tool to make changes to the CSS on the fly so you can make sure it looks the way you want and then copy the changes in your project.

Comment: justin, no worries, i can do the research.  I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @ofilha - Whether it is a warning or not is fully dependent upon your requirements. For example, most web projects use `display:none` CSS to hide the contents of the page when JavaScript is disabled (using `<noscript></noscript>`) and show an appropriate message (as meta redirection can be blocked on some browses) but the contents of the page can easily uncovered by removing that CSS. Even Google APIs do this because it's just a message and doesn't indicate any security constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to having hidden fields which I feel interesting is having  tags instead of label and by doing that you could retrieve the text value in the div tag.